# Click on certain pixel of Canvas using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, driver, action

I'm starting with selenium and I found the problem. I have a canva with some "hot points". For example I have canvas 230x230. My "hot point" is 4,144. I want click on this point on this canvas. Basically I want to click on cordinates 4,144 on canvas.

So I found a function move to element with offset. But nothing is clicked right now. What is wrong with my code?:

```
   from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import time
    webdriver_path = "****"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path)
    path= "https://www.google.com"
    driver.get(path)
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/canvas')
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(element,4,144).click().perform()
```

Comment: Is the website/url with the canvas element publicly accessable? Please share.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.